# Automatically deleted project in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

For the reasons of electricity my computer has shut down. That time my Netbeans project was running. I built up this project a few minutes back. Starting up the computer, the Netbeans project source file is gone. How can I retrieve my project files?

Comment: You try to save a 'few minutes' of your time by using a lot more of people's time. Not reasonable. -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have the project in the NetbeansProject folder.

Use open project button and it should put it back if the sources and .project are there.

So, if nbproject folder exists then you can open the project.  If the src is there then you have the source files.  If not you might be screwed.  That's where SVN is handy.

If they are gone, then it depends on the sensitivity and importance of the code.  You may need to pay a service to extract the bits from your hard drive if they are even still there.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to select (highlight) the project that contained the ZIP file. Under Versioning, select Local History -> Revert Deleted and see if your ZIP file comes back.